# how to count digits of a phonenumber(included 0) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript , And want to count digits of a var str,
in the code below var str is 6 digits (012345), but when i run this code it is showing answer 4. i tried to search on google but answer not found;
how to get correct answer and fix it ?

my code

```
 var str = 012345;
 var x = String(str);
var n = x.length;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "var str is[" + n + "] Digits";
```

Comment: `012345` is not a _String_. It is a number literal. You can't recover prefixed `0`s from a number literal. Also, it may be interpreted as octal, be careful! `012345; // 5349 (oct -> dec)`

Comment: You can't do it. Preceding 0s are all ignored except for the last one, which denotes that the number is to be represented as octal i.e. 000000012 will store 10. Instead of trying to "fix" this, try to rething your solution. Do you really need this? I see no practical purpose for this, because even in a mathematical context, preceding zeros mean nothing..

Comment: ** "Do you really need this?"**  Yes i  need it

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the code with:

```
var str = "012345";
var n = str.length;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "var str is[" + n + "] Digits";
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize you phone number as string using quotes.

```
var str = '0123213'
```

And use `length` property to get its length

Answer (score 1):

If you were to actually have a mixed letter/number *string* from which you wanted to get the number of digits you could use a regex. `match` creates an array of all the matches in the string - in this case `\d`, a digit (`g` says to check the whole of the string, not give up the search when the first digit has been found.) You can then check the length of the returned array.

```
'01xx2s3eg345'.match(/\d/g).length; // 7
```